# How to use getCurrencyInstance and format in low api?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-debug, android-developer-api

I am getting an error in the following code:

```
private void displayPrice (int number) {

    TextView price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
    price.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 14): android.icu.text.NumberFormat#getCurrencyInstance
```

Android API 24 can use this. How can I use this in low API like `API 15`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your import to use [java.text.NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) (available from API 1) instead of [android.icu.text.NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/NumberFormat.html) (available from API 24).

The [ICU4J framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/icu4j-framework.html) provides better internationalization support, but it is not required.