# Cannot resolve symbol Number Format android

Tags: android

This is my code

```
private void displayPrice(int number) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
        priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
    }}
```

I am getting Cannot Resolve symbol"Number Format".

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390618/1343788

Comment: Did you import the `NumberFormat` class?  More specifically, does this import appear at the top of your Java file, or does Android Studio flag `NumberFormat` by placing it in red text?

Answer (score 4):

You should import the NumberFormat class from java.text

Your import statement should like below.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat
```

Answer (score 4):

Import this its working

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the line

```
import.java.text.NumberFormat
```

manually.